# awk edit column value if numeric

Tags: shell-script, awk

What I would like to do is search for lines where the first column does not begin with 'rs' or 'chr' THEN if those lines begin with a number, append 'chr' to the first column value, otherwise leave as it was - no appending.

I have the following code:

```
awk '((!($1 ~ /rs/ || $1 ~ /chr/)) && $1 ~ /^[[:0-9:]]|$/) {$1 = "chr"$1}1' filename > newfilename
```

This is good but appends 'chr' to all first column values that do not begin with 'rs' or 'chr'. There are some values in this column that I do not want to change and these all begin with letters (a-z). I only want to change the values which start with numbers (0-9).

Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know [crossposting on Stack Exchange networks is discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).  I think [your question at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188070/awk-edit-column-value-if-numeric) is probably the better spot than this one

Comment: you are aware that 'begins with digit' also includes 'not rs nor chr', so you could just match lines with digits in the first column?

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments by Fiximan, looking for a digit automatically filters out 'rs' and 'chr'. So if you want to prepend lines starting with a digit with 'chr' you can do the following:

```
awk '{if ($1 ~ /^[:0-9:]/) printf "chr%s\n", $0; else printf "%s\n", $0;}' filename > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

using `sed`

```
sed 's/^[0-9]/chr&/' file
```